# Integer solutions for $n$ for $|{\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{2011}}| < 1$

Tags: inequality, diophantine-equations, integers

$$|{\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{2011}}| < 1$$

What is the number of positive integer $n$ values, which satisfy the above inequality.

**My effort:**

$ 
({\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{2011}})^2 < 1 \\n + 2011 -2\sqrt{2011n} < 1\\ n+2010<2\sqrt{2011n}\\ n^2+2 \times 2010 \times n +2010^2<4 \times 2011n  \\n^2 -4024n +2010^2 < 0 $

But it seems this won't lead me for desired answer.

Comment: Aha. You have 200 reputation-you should realize you should post your effort.

Comment: Your attempt also works, what you want is the number of integers between the two roots of that polynomial, in other words the number of integers between the two solutions to $x^2-4024x-2010^2=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{n}\in(\sqrt{2011}-1,\sqrt{2011}+1)\iff n\in ( (\sqrt{2011}-1)^2,(\sqrt{2011}+1)^2)=(2012-2\sqrt{2011},2012+2\sqrt{2011})$

There are $2\lfloor2\sqrt{2011} \rfloor + 1$ integers in this range.

We approximate $\sqrt{2011}$ as $44.8$ and we find the answer is $2\cdot 89 + 1=179$.

Comment: A short proof that $\sqrt{2011}$ is between $44.5$ and $45$ follows by noting that $44^2=1936,45^2=2025$ and that the square root function lies above its secant lines. Thus $\sqrt{2011}>44+\frac{2011-1936}{2025-1936}=44+\frac{75}{89}$ while $\sqrt{2011}<\sqrt{2025}=45$.

Comment: Nice${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

$|\sqrt n - \sqrt{2011}| <1 \iff -1 < \sqrt n - \sqrt {2011 }< 1 \iff 
\sqrt{2011} - 1 <\sqrt n < \sqrt {2011} + 1 \iff (\sqrt{2011} - 1)^2 < n < (\sqrt{2011}+1)^2.$  You should be able to finish it from here.

Answer (score 2):

Brute force says that $(\sqrt{2011}-1)^2\leq n\leq (\sqrt{2011}+1)^2$. So you can use a calculator to find the lower and upper bound integer values: $1923\leq n\leq 
2101$, do there are $2101-1923+1$ integer values $n$.

Algebraically, we see that $(\sqrt{2011}-1)^2 = 2012-2\sqrt{2011}$ and $(\sqrt{2011}+1)^2=2012+2\sqrt{2011}$. So a non-calculator value is $1+2\lfloor2\sqrt{2011}\rfloor$.

These both give the value $179$.